# All element of an array as key in an Object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to construct an array of object from another array and object.

```
let assets = [
               {id: '1', count: 1, skills: ["teach", "play"]},
               {id: '2', count: 1, skills: ["write", "surf"]},
               {id: '3', count: 2, skills: ["run"]},
               {id: '4', count: 3, skills: ["teach", "run", "hike"]}
             ]
```

And then I take all the unique skills available above.

```
let uniqueSkills = ["teach", "play", "write", "surf", "run", "hike"]
```

Every element in uniqueSkills array must be a key in an object. And if that key is present in assets array, I want to store that particular object's `id` and `count`.

I am expecting my final object to be something like this which I will have to use to plot a graph.

```
{
  teach: [{id: 1, count: 1},{id: 4, count: 3}],
  play: [{id: 1, count: 1}],
  write: [{id: 2, count: 1}],
  surf: [{id: 2, count: 1}],
  run: [{id: 3, count: 2}, {id: 4, count: 3}],
  hike: [{id: 4, count: 3}]
}
```

Comment: can you show us what you've tried please ?

Comment: Sounds good. What's your question, and what have you actually tried?

Comment: What you need is `Array.map()` / `Array.forEach()` and `Array.includes()`. And arrays of course. The rest is up to you.

Comment: I tried a couple of things but it didn't work. May be I should have added them too.

Comment: @kaleem it's never too late to add what you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array. [Destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the parameter to get `skills` and [`rest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) of the properties separately. Then loop through `skills` and add/update the key in the accumulator

```js
const assets=[{id:'1',count:1,skills:["teach","play"]},{id:'2',count:1,skills:["write","surf"]},{id:'3',count:2,skills:["run"]},{id:'4',count:3,skills:["teach","run","hike"]}]

const output = assets.reduce((acc, { skills, ...rest }) => {
  skills.forEach(s => {
    acc[s] = acc[s] || [];
    acc[s].push(rest)
  })
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(output)
```

(Check the browser's console for the actual output. Snippet isn't displaying it properly)

Answer (score 1):

```
let finalObj = {};
uniqueSkills.map( (skill) => {
  finalObj[skill] = assets.filter( asset => asset.skills.includes(skill) )
  .map( asset => ({id: asset.id, count: asset.count}) );  
})
```

This is a bit complicated, so let me break it up for you:

1. going through all uniqueSkills with `Array.map()`.
2. for each skill we create a property with the skill name inside our final object.
3. filter the assets array to remove any objects that do not include that skill in their `skills` property.
4. on the array which comes back from filter- return an array which includes only the `id` and `count` propperties, and put that array inside the property created at step 2.

for more info on array functions: [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without using `reduce` that relies on function generators instead and uses `.filter` to acquire the desired filtered values.

below code will iterate through all the unique skills and, for each of them, will build up an object.

It's not meant to be more efficient or whatever, it's just another way of accomplishing the task and is meant to be elastic and easy to maintain. Moreover, it may also be possible to don't rely on any array prototype at all.

Below approach allows for further object transformations if needed.

```js
let assets = [
 {id: '1', count: 1, skills: ["teach", "play"]},
 {id: '2', count: 1, skills: ["write", "surf"]},
 {id: '3', count: 2, skills: ["run"]},
 {id: '4', count: 3, skills: ["teach", "run", "hike"]}
];
let uniqueSkills = ["teach", "play", "write", "surf", "run", "hike"];

// Aggregates the source results by looking for uniqueSkills in its skills property.
function* aggregateByUniqueSkills(source, uniqueSkills) {
  // loop each uniques skill.
  for (var skill of [...new Set(uniqueSkills)]) { // <-- new Set ensures there are no duplicates.
    const skillSet = {[skill]: []}; // <-- define a new object with a key and a default empty array value.
    for ({id, count} of source.filter(i => i.skills && i.skills.indexOf(skill) > -1)) { // acquire all the elements in the source whose skills contains the current skill.
      skillSet[skill].push({id, count}); // push the value.
    }
    yield skillSet; // yield the current result.
  }
}

console.log(Object.assign({}, ...aggregateByUniqueSkills(assets, uniqueSkills)));
```

Comment: Yes, as you have already mentioned, I believe it will take more time when there is a huge data set though it solves the problem.

Comment: @kaleem actually it will iterate both arrays less times than other solutions, it's likely more efficient on larger datasets and less efficient on smaller datasets. Other approachs implies looping the dataset first and look for skills in it. In my case, I do the opposite: i filter the larger dataset according to the smallest one, hence it should be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @briosheje. Will compare all the solutions with big data set to see performance difference.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no short way to get it done. Just a simple algorithm.
Here is a solution that works.

```js
let assets = [
    { id: '1', count: 1, skills: ["teach", "play"] },
    { id: '2', count: 1, skills: ["write", "surf"] },
    { id: '3', count: 2, skills: ["run"] },
    { id: '4', count: 3, skills: ["teach", "run", "hike"] }
];

// Filter unique keys into an array
let skillKeys = [];
assets.forEach(element => {
    skillKeys = [...new Set(skillKeys.concat(element['skills']))];
});

// Final refined result
let refined = {};
let temp = [];
skillKeys.forEach(sKey => {
    temp = [];
    assets.forEach(a => {
        if (a['skills'].includes(sKey)) {
            temp.push({ id: a['id'], count: a['count'] });
        }
    })
    refined[sKey] = temp;
});

console.log(refined);
```